# Imitating button click with UIGestureRecognized

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

Having added a `UITapGestureRecognized` to a `UIView`, how do I parse the view for ie. changing the background color during the tap? The purpose of this is to imitate a button click.

```
UIView *locationView = [[UIView alloc] init];
locationView.tag = 11;
locationView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
locationView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[locationView addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(promptForLocation)]];
```

Let's say I want `locationView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]` right after the tap gesture. Would you just implement it in the target action or is there a specific implementation for this?

**Update**:
This is my final code inspired by @0x7fffffff

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // ...
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressDetectedLocation:)];
    longPress.allowableMovement = 50.0f;
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.05;
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress2 = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressDetectedPhoto:)];
    longPress2.allowableMovement = 50.0f;
    longPress2.minimumPressDuration = 0.05;
    [leftView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
    [rightView addGestureRecognizer:longPress2];
    // ...
}

- (BOOL)longPressDetected:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if ([self.view hasFirstResponder]) {
        return NO;
    }
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [sender.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(4/255.0) green:(129/255.0) blue:(241/255.0) alpha:1]];
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) {
        [sender.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
    CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:sender.view];
    return sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded && location.x > 0 && location.x < sender.view.frame.size.width && location.y > 0 && location.y < sender.view.frame.size.height;
}

- (void)longPressDetectedLocation:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if ([self longPressDetected:sender]) {
        [self promptForLocation];
    }
}

- (void)longPressDetectedPhoto:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if ([self longPressDetected:sender]) {
        [self promptForPhoto];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you're trying to imitate a button click, I'm assuming you'd want the view to revert to its original state after the touch ends. To do this, you'll want to use a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` instead of a `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

With a tap gesture, the recognizer isn't detected until the touch ends, so you'd effectively be highlighting the view as soon as you lift your finger. To get around this, use the long press gesture its `minimumPressDuration` property set to 0.0. Then in its selector, check the state of the sending gesture; If it has just begun, change the background color, and if it has ended revert back to the original color.

Here's an example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
    [myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressDetected:)];
    [longPress setAllowableMovement:50.0f];
    [longPress setMinimumPressDuration:0.0];
    [myView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
}

- (void)longPressDetected:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [sender.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) {
        [sender.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%d",sender.state);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedMethod:)];
    [locationView addGestureRecognizer:gr];
```

This is method

```
-(void)tappedMethod:(UIGestureRecognizer *)ge
{
  // write relavent code here;
  locationView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```